# I am new In spring & Hibernate How To add profile image path in database using Springs 3 MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Value Object Class

```
    package com.admin.modelVO;

    import java.sql.Timestamp;


    public class UserProfileVO{


    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String dob;
    private String emailId;
    private String contactNo;
    private String gender;
    private String photo;
    private Timestamp createdDate;
    private Boolean status;
    private Integer rollId;




    public Integer getRollId() {
        return rollId;
    }
    public void setRollId(Integer rollId) {
        this.rollId = rollId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }
    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }
    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }
    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }
    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }
    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    public Timestamp getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(Timestamp createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }


    }
```

Second Controller

```
package com.admin.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.admin.modelVO.UserProfileVO;
import com.admin.service.UserProfileService;

@Controller
public class UserProfileController{


    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/userprofile1",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userprofile1(@ModelAttribute("UserProfileVO") UserProfileVO userProfileVO,ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        return "userprofile1";
        }
    @RequestMapping(value="/userprofile",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userprofile(@ModelAttribute("UserProfileVO") UserProfileVO userProfileVO,ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,RedirectAttributes redirect){


            String result=userProfileService.listUserProfile(userProfileVO);

                request.setAttribute("userlist", result);

            System.out.println("dfghdfg"+result);



            return "success";
        }
}
```

3.DaoImplement

```
package com.admin.daoImpl;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.admin.dao.UserProfileDao;
import com.admin.entity.Usermaster;
import com.admin.modelVO.UserProfileVO;

@Repository
public class UserProfileDaoImpl implements UserProfileDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Date date=new Date();

    public String listUserProfile(UserProfileVO userProfileVO) {
        String userId=null;

        Usermaster userMaster=new Usermaster();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        userMaster.setUsername(userProfileVO.getUserName());
        userMaster.setPassword(userProfileVO.getPassword());
        userMaster.setFname(userProfileVO.getfName());
        userMaster.setLname(userProfileVO.getfName());
        userMaster.setDob(userProfileVO.getDob());
        userMaster.setEmail(userProfileVO.getEmailId());
        userMaster.setGender(userProfileVO.getGender());
        userMaster.setContactNo(userProfileVO.getContactNo());
        userMaster.setPhoto(userProfileVO.getPhoto());
        userMaster.setStatus(true);
        userMaster.setCreatedDate(date);
        userMaster.setRoleId(2);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(userMaster);
        System.out.println("dsfsf"+userMaster);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        return userId;
    }

}
```

I want to upload profile picture with registration page and i want to set contxt path on database and image is perticulor folder. i will post you DaoImpl VO and Controller where we put the code and my object is "PHOTO" so i want to stored it

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following method to handle image uploading i.e. multipart request. You can not this method directly in your code. This is for understanding only.

For this you will need :

commons-fileupload.jar
and
commons-io.jar

```
public String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("description: " + request.getParameter("description"));

    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
        for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload) {

            System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

            if (!aFile.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                aFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + aFile.getOriginalFilename()));
            }
        }
    }

    // returns to the view "Result"
    return "Result";
}
```

Here: "saveDirectory" string variable can be any path on your server, where you want to store files.

in configuration you will need to add:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);

    return multipartResolver;
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
// get absolute path of the application    
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
String saveDirectory = context.getRealPath("");
System.out.println("saveDirectory = " + saveDirectory);
```

You dont have to store whole path to the file. Just store file name (that you can give any unique name every time). So in DAOImpl write code for storing filename.

Comment: where we write this code  Controller OR DAOIMPLEMENTATION

Comment: In controller. @Abhinay

Comment: its work but how to set url of image as wll as folder wher image is stored please help me and where we write code daoimpls and how please in details.........................

Comment: please see "edit". 
PS: just simply add `obj.setPhoto(fileName);` thats it in DAOImpl. 
And please do some effort to code. You can't get it ready for your specified app.